# What the value of "chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()" represents?

Tags: c++, random, c++-chrono

```
cout << chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() << "\n"; // it prints a 14-digit value
```

Is is the number of nanoseconds passed since 1970?

Comment: Both the epoch and the resolution of `std::chrono::steady_clock` are unspecified.  So you can't rely on "nanoseconds" and you can't rely on "since 1970".  `steady_clock` is not intended to be compared against a wall clock or calendar.

Comment: [From here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) _This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring intervals_

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm using this value as a seed for `mt19937_64`

Comment: Use `std::random_device` instead.

Comment: @sweenish `std::random_device` is allowed to produce the same output every time it is used

Comment: Yes it is. Good thing you only need it once. On what hardware will that actually occur, and is it hardware that OP is using? Time is predictable. If that's the argument, might as well just use 4 from a fair dice roll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is is the number of nanoseconds passed since 1970?

Very unlikely.

It is the number of *some duration unit* passed since *some time*.  Neither the unit nor the epoch is standardized.

This may not sound useful, and a single reading of `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` arguably **isn't very useful**.  (Beyond, say, seeding a random number generator perhaps)

`steady_clock` readings are intended to be compared against other `steady_clock` readings.  It is useful for measuring elapsed time.

The `count()` is only useful if you cast the duration to a known duration period.